# share link facebook update status wall using c#(facebook SDK)

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-wall

I am searching three days but not find solution of my problems. I hope you will help me solve my problems.

I succeeded to post on wall. But there is a problem when I post ds wall nobody (even my friends too) can see my post and not post on update status. Only I can see the wall post. I checked my facebook settings and wall posts property is public.

```
string[] extendedPermissions = new[] { "publish_stream", "offline_access" }; 
var fbLoginDialog = new FacebookLoginDialog(appId, extendedPermissions); 
fbLoginDialog.ShowDialog(); 
if (fbLoginDialog.FacebookOAuthResult != null) { 
  if (fbLoginDialog.FacebookOAuthResult.IsSuccess) { 
    var fb = new FacebookClient(fbLoginDialog.FacebookOAuthResult.AccessToken); 
      dynamic result = fb.Get("/me"); 
      string firstName = result.first_name; 
      string lastName = result.last_name; 
      string id = result.id; 
      dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject(); 
      parameters.message = "Check out this funny article"; 
      parameters.link = "http://www.example.com/article.html"; 
      parameters.picture = "http://www.example.com/article-thumbnail.jpg"; 
      parameters.name = "Article Title"; 
      parameters.caption = "Caption for the link"; 
      parameters.description = "Longer description of the link"; 
      parameters.actions = new { name = "View on Zombo", link = "http://www.zombo.com", }; 
      parameters.privacy = new { value = "ALL_FRIENDS", }; 
      parameters.targeting = new { countries = "US", regions = "6,53", locales = "6", }; 
      dynamic result1 = fb.Post("me/feed", parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying the following:

- change `parameters.privacy = new { value = "CUSTOM"};` and see if that helps.
- be sure the friends are qualified in the targeting list.
- be sure your app is not in sandbox mode otherwise, only developers/testers of the app can see the postings from that app.